# Broken link in the Users tab

Tags: bug

I was having a look at [the Users tab](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users) and found this broken link at the bottom of the page:

**[weekly / monthly / quarterly reputation leagues](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/week/aviation)**

Comment: I believe that the leagues aren't available during private beta, but you are correct that the broken link shouldn't be there while the leagues are unavailable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality won't work while the site is in private beta. Arguably, we shouldn't be displaying that (and probably a few others hidden in nooks & crannies) during the private beta phase, I'll have a look at it.

By design that the leagues aren't live until the site goes public, probably a bug/oversight that we even show the link to begin with.